# Robotium - choose apk to test

Tags: android, robotium

When i execute my tests, all is done with the current BuildVariant. Is there a way to choose BuilVariant automatically ? I know if i change it (in the dropdown) from android studio it works as expected but it is not an acceptable solution.

I have seen i can manage test with productFlavor here ==> [Robotium - testing specific flavors in Android Studio with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091912/robotium-testing-specific-flavors-in-android-studio-with-gradle)

but this solution is not pratical

In fact, it will be nice if I can manage application in robotium for one test but I have found nothing

Here is the code I want

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Solo.Config config = new Solo.Config();
    config.commandLogging = true;
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), config);
    getActivity();
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    super.tearDown();
}

// Test on apk1
public void test1Screenshot() {
    String name = "1";
    solo.waitForActivity(MainActivity.class);
    solo.takeScreenshot(name);
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Robotium-Screenshots/", name + ".jpg");
    final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    assertTrue(solo.waitForCondition(new Condition() {
        @Override
        public boolean isSatisfied() {
            return file.exists();
        }
    }, TIMEOUT));
}

// Test on apk2
public void test2Screenshot() {
    String name = "2";
    solo.waitForActivity(MainActivity.class);
    solo.takeScreenshot(name);
    final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Robotium-Screenshots/", name + ".jpg");
    final int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    assertTrue(solo.waitForCondition(new Condition() {
        @Override
        public boolean isSatisfied() {
            return file.exists();
        }
    }, TIMEOUT));
}
```

So my question is : Is there a way to determine package name to test from robotium ?

ps : robotium 5.5.3