# Android: How to use lower minSdkVersion than declared in library (uiautomator-v18)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I migrated an older Android app to Android-Studio/Gradle. The test need `uiautomator-v18` which requires `minSdkVersion=18`. However, I would like to have the `minSdkVersion` set to 15 or 16.

There are many questions on SO over the same thing, but I am just not able to resolve this problem.

Exerpt AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.searcher"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>

    <!-- ... -->

</manifest>
```

The build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.searcher"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        testApplicationId "com.example.searcher.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/javawriter-2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject.jar')

    androidTestCompile(
        'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0',
        'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1',
        'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1',
        'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1',
        'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3',
        'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.5',
        'junit:junit:4.12',
        'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.1',
        'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1'
    )
}
```

The above gives the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 18 declared in library [com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1] /mypath/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support.test.uiautomator/uiautomator-v18/2.1.1/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18" to force usage
```

But I am already using the `overrideLibrary`.

If this is not possible, is it possible to have different `minSdkVersion` for "main" and "androidTest"?

**EDIT**:
After adding the flavors, I was able to run the tests using build variant `tstDebug`. However, building it with `prdDebug` ends in an error saying that there are unknown stuff in the androidTest (example: `package org.hamcrest does not exist`). The modified excerpt of `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.searcher"
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 6
    versionName "0.5.0"
}

productFlavors {
    prd {
        minSdkVersion 15
    }
    tst {
        minSdkVersion 18
        testApplicationId "com.example.searcher.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}

// And instead of "androidTestCompile" use "tstCompile"
```

Is it not possible to tell "Android Studio" that it should build the app without `androidTest`?

Comment: Do you tried to change the version  in AndroidManifest of your overrideLibrary  ?

Comment: @Sree: Yes, same issue.

Comment: I finally could make it run with "flavors": I failed to name the flavored tests correctly. So, for flavor "dev" the test folder should be `androidTestDev`. Which I found in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28092437/3045181)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set different minSdkVersion for testAndroid than for main app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585289/set-different-minsdkversion-for-testandroid-than-for-main-app)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to have a product flavor for your tests:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        production {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }
        uiTest {
            minSdkVersion 18
        }
    }
...
}
```

And then run the tests on the `uiTest` flavor builds.

Comment: Sorry for trying it out late. Finally I got the tests running with a lower `minSdkVersion`. What I missed was setting the build-variant in "Android Studio". Without it the tests could not be run. I preferred if this were possible with `overrideLibrary` (as it seems to me this is its purpose). But well, enough time spent.

Comment: If instead of a product flavor, you need to increase the minSdkVersion in a buildType, just wrap the minSdkVersion with defaultConfig, like this: `espresso {
            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 18
            } }`

Answer (score 13):

Did you put `<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary ...>` in `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`?

If so, remove it from `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and try to put the following xml in `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml`.

(Don't forget `android:minSdkVersion="18"`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="YOUR PACKAGE NAME"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"
        />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `AndroidManifest.xml` in src/androidTest/ is auto-generated. If I use `minSdkVersion` in the gradle.build, it will create an `AndroidManifest.xml` in build/ with the values from gradle.build. If I leave `minSdkVersion` undefined, it will use version `1` as default, which results in an error, too.

Comment: @tokosh More precisely, `minSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` and `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` are merged into `build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`. So, storing`src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` is significant.

I confirmed it in the following environment:

- Android Studio 1.5.1
- Android Gradle Plugin 1.5.0
-  `minSdkVersion` in `app/build.gradle`: 16

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, the merged AndroidManifest.xml still has  `android:minSdkVersion="16"`. It is no problem. Declaring `tools:overrideLibrary` will prevent the manifest merger to fail in compilation.