# How to specify unit test folder in two-dimension flavor

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I had a project that have two-dimension flavor.
e.g. flavorDimensions "device", "fruit"

1. mobileBanana
2. mobileApple
3. stbBanana
4. stbApple

All building result is fine, and I want to put unit test only for **stbApple** when select **Build Variant** in Android Studio.
How to achieve this goal ?

I had tried below experiment, but still fail.

1.Set sourceSets (fail, other build variant still run this folder)

```
sourceSets {
        mobile {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/mobile/assets']
        }

        stbApple {
            androidTest {
                // Other build variant still run unit test in this folder.......
                java.srcDirs += ['src/androidTestStbApple/java']
            }
        }
    }
```

2.Give androidTestStbApple folder in src folder, as [doc](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Flavors-and-build-types-support) said, we would not give specified folder in Gradle, it can distinguish build variant by folder.
and the result is failed,too.

It seems two-dimension flavor is not supported in gradle / android studio now for unit testing. (one-dimension can work successfully)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define unit tests for multi-flavors project in this way:

```
 dependencies {
    androidTestFlavor1Compile "..."

    //In your case androidTestStbAppleCompile         
}
```

You can use this folder as sourceSet:

```
 src/androidTestStbApple/
```

In this way each flavor has its own task to run tests.In your case

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTestStbAppleDebug
```

Comment: Thank you, and i found that my gradle version is too old : 1.0.0, it can not support multiple-flavor as my question.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti How to combine unit test for some flavor which refer to same set of unit tests in source sets except main tests, so I want to merge androidTestStbApple androidTestStbBanana test to a single folder because in my case both has same unit tests

Comment: I dont get the answer, where are you going to put that ?