# How do I prevent a flavor specific unit test from being compiled in another flavor?

Tags: android, junit, android-productflavors

I'm trying to do this, but with a single dimension so it's simpler: [How to specify unit test folder in two-dimension flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643024/how-to-specify-unit-test-folder-in-two-dimension-flavor)

app module build.gradle specifies 2 flavors, free and premium:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
     optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions 'someFlavor'
    productFlavors {
        premium {
            applicationIdSuffix '.premium'
        }

        free
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'src/debug/kotlin'
        release.java.srcDirs += 'src/release/kotlin'

        free {
            java.srcDirs += 'src/free/kotlin'
            test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
        }

        premium {
            java.srcDirs += 'src/premium/kotlin'
            test.java.srcDirs += ['src/test/kotlin', 
        'src/testPremium/kotlin']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Android Studio's Project view shows:

```
app
  src
    free
      kotlin (empty folder for now)
    main
      java
        com.example.myapplication
          MainActivity.java
    premium
      kotlin
        com.example.myapplication
          PremiumFile.kt
    test
      kotlin
        com.example.myapplication
          MainTest.kt
    testPremium
      kotlin
        com.example.myapplication
          PremiumTest.kt
```

PremiumFile.kt

```
class PremiumFile {
  companion obnject {
    const val PREMIUM_NUM = 10
  }
}
```

MainTest.kt

```
class MainTest {
    @Test
    fun basicMainTest() {
      assertEquals(1, 1)
    }
}
```

PremiumTest.kt

```
class PremiumTest {
    @Test
    fun premiumTest() {
        assertEquals(PremiumFile.Premium_NUM, 1)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I lack any unit tests specific to the free flavor.  I expected that running `./gradlew compileFreeReleaseUnitTestKotlin` would compile the shared unit test inside `src/test`, but it also compiles the Premium unit tests inside `src/testPremium`.  How can I make sure that PremiumTest.kt is only compiled for Premium tasks such as `./gradlew compilePremiumReleaseUnitTestKotlin`?

Comment: Out of interest can I ask why you would want this behaviour?

Comment: I have a Premium flavor for paid users.  Premium tests test Premium features.  compilePremiumReleaseUnitTestKotlin would compile tests for free and premium.  compileFreeReleaseUnitTestKotlin would only compile tests for free inside src/test.

Comment: so you mean you want to speed up your build by doing less tests for each flavor?

Comment: I dont care about build time.  I want to compile src/testPremium and src/test for premium flavor, src/test for anything else

Comment: in the post I added every file you need to reproduce.  Simply create a new empty android application, copy/paste my build.gradle and create the additional directories and files I've pasted above.  Try running ./gradlew compileFreeReleaseUnitTestKotlin and ./gradlew compilePremiumReleaseUnitTestKotlin.

Comment: Could you share the complete sample project code on GitHub or somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `gradlew sourceSets` on your project, you'll get the following section among the others :

```
test
----
Compile configuration: testCompile
build.gradle name: android.sourceSets.test
Java sources: [app\src\test\java, app\src\test\kotlin, app\src\testPremium\kotlin]
Java-style resources: [app\src\test\resources]

testPremium
-----------
Compile configuration: testPremiumCompile
build.gradle name: android.sourceSets.testPremium
Java sources: [app\src\testPremium\java]
Java-style resources: [app\src\testPremium\resources]
```

As you can see `app\src\testPremium\kotlin` is in the main `test` configuration, not in the `testPremium`. And because `test` is shared among all the flavors, its sources included in all of them (e.g. `testFree` configuration will include sources specified in both `test` and `testFree` configurations).

It also suggests you how to fix the issue - use `testPremium` in the configuration block. So instead of

```
premium {
    java.srcDirs += 'src/premium/kotlin' 
    test.java.srcDirs += ['src/test/kotlin', 'src/testPremium/kotlin']
}
```

Write

```
premium {
    java.srcDirs += 'src/premium/kotlin'
}
test{
    java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin'
}
testPremium {
    java.srcDirs += 'src/testPremium/kotlin'
}
```

So `gradlew sourseSets` will give you:

```
test
----
Compile configuration: testCompile
build.gradle name: android.sourceSets.test
Java sources: [app\src\test\java, app\src\test\kotlin]
Java-style resources: [app\src\test\resources]

testPremium
-----------
Compile configuration: testPremiumCompile
build.gradle name: android.sourceSets.testPremium
Java sources: [app\src\testPremium\java, app\src\testPremium\kotlin]
Java-style resources: [app\src\testPremium\resources]
```

Because `test` does not exist in `AndroidSourceSet`, it's not a 'type' of sources like 'java', 'resources' and so on. Instead, `test` is another instance of `AndroidSourceSet`. So when you're writing `test.java.srcDirs`, you are actually configuring this top-level `test` source set, not tests inside `premium`.