# How to make a separate test package of androidTest

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I have an android APK which has some androidTest(Instrumentation) which tests the API in the app. I intend to separate out the androidTest into a different headless service which does the following:

1. Install the before said app
2. Test the API

I plan on doing this so that the APK and the tests are separated, and the QA and Dev team need not depend on each other but do their development separately.

My question is, is this possible?
How do I proceed with making a separate test package with a service/or headless app.

Comment: Install the before said app means?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373655/test-package-for-different-flavors-in-android-studio

Comment: @mudit_sen the android APK i mentioned to start with.